# SQL Server 2008R2 Cannot connect mapped NAS anymore after migrate to windows 10

Tags: sql-server, networking, connection, mapping, windows-10

I've migrated to windows 10 from windows 8.1.

Everything seems running fine except for the connection to a mapped NAS (Buffalo TS 4200) in my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

I've access to all files and NAS directories in Win explorer. I've tried several things without success. Buffalo said NAS is Windows 10 compatible.

Firewall changes config doesn't help.

My T-SQL script  has not been changed since windows 8.1

I get an error 58

> System error cannot execute operation...

when executing the connection script.

Why is it not working anymore in Windows 10? Privilege right access? But where to look for?

Here is the unchanged main SQL line :

```
 exec xp_cmdshell 'net use x: \\Buffalo\xxx\xxx '
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is  the solution I found to solve this issue  appeared after Migration to Windows 10. As mentioned before, it seems related to access rights with W10. So you have to include Password and Name as these syntax:

> net use [{devicename | *}] [\computername\sharename[\volume] [{password | *}]] >[/user:[domainname]username]

More practically in my case :

> EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use U: \Buffalo\xxx\xxx PASSWORD /User: XXX'

Hope this will help.

NB : I experienced same access problems with other softwares like BackUp tools and resolved it same way forcing explicitly password and login. Windows 10 is more restrictive than previous OS versions.